# need an efficient query for selecting from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

One table A, looks like this:

```
table A:
==========
ID       NAME
1        Ted
2        John
3        Sandy
4        Robert
5        Helen

table B:
=========
CONTRIBUTION          CONTRIBUTOR_ID
100                   1
200                   3
150                   3
270                   2
30                    1
```

Assuming table B is very big and table A is small, I would like to pseudo iterate on this.
- take first ID from table A
- search for the first occurrence in table B, if found add to result
- if not continue to next ID in table A.
- repeat until end of table A

I would like a list of all ID's from table A that exist in table B
So the result here would be:

```
1
2
3
```

Of course, the tables are properly indexed.

any idea how to write this efficiently in MySQL?
Thanks

Comment: Define "first occurrence".

Comment: but wouldn't join just sum up to the whole length of table B? magnitude of n

Comment: just any occurrence, not first or last. I just need the ID's of all those who have ever "contributed"

Answer (score 5):

Or just simply

```
select distinct contributor_id 
from table B
```

Comment: Assuming that all contributors in TableB exist in TableA.

Comment: True.  but I would expect a decent design in which there is a foreign_key to A.id

Comment: @avk:- In that case using a JOIN would be a good idea. Also try to create index on your table as that would help in quick retrieval!

Comment: @Ted:- The ideal way to proceed is to JOIN the two tables. Also as you mentioned that your table B is huge so it is recommended to use Index in your table as that would help you in getting your records faster.

Comment: @Rahul, but isn't JOIN requiring a magnitude of N? I want to take it down to K, meaning -> the given size of table A

Comment: @Ted:- Got that, but I am afraid that it is not possible as you mentioned that your table B is quite huge so I dont think you can bring it down to K.

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct ID from tableA inner join tableB
on table.ID=tableB.CONTRIBUTOR_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select tA.ID 
from tableA tA inner join tableB tB on tA.ID = tB.CONTRIBUTOR_ID
group by tA.ID
```

Comment: i don't see need of  useing group by here.

Comment: @SuchitKumar:- Using a `group by` is very much same as using a `distinct` provided there is proper indexing on the column. And since the table B is huge, so I assume that OP will(*must*) create index on the column.

Answer (score 0):

the query

`SELECT * from A,B where A.ID = B.CONTRIBUTOR_ID`

would select all rows with an existing ID in both tables. It would leave out all rows in A which never have contributed (not exist in B)

**EDIT**:

to only get the IDs of those who ever contributed, try:

```
SELECT ID FROM A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CONTRIBUTOR_ID FROM B where ID = CONTRIBUTOR_ID)
```

Comment: do not use * if you don't need everything.

Comment: It would also return one row for every occurrence in table B (not just once for each contributor) and would not be particularly efficient.

Comment: @MarkBannister yepp, agread to the no. of rows. the rest depends on indexes.

Comment: Indexes are unlikely to help the first query - `select *` means that the query has to access the whole row of table B (not just the contents of the index), while the need for **all** IDs in table A is likely to mean that it will need to access all rows from table B. The second query would be significantly more efficient in most RDBMSs (since the optimizer would normally short-circuit the query on finding the first existing record in the sub-query) but my understanding of MySQL is that its optimizer doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

If table B can contain contributors that don't exist in table A, then I suggest trying:

```
select tA.ID 
from tableA tA 
inner join (select distinct contributor_id from tableB) tB 
        on tA.ID = tB.CONTRIBUTOR_ID
```

(assuming you have an index on Contributor_ID on tableB)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by using subquery

```
Select distinct ID from A where ID in(select CONTRIBUTOR_ID from B)
```